# Como puedo hacer que el usuario repita una accion de un ciclo o bucle hasta que lo haga bien

Tags: c++, c, dev-c++

Esto es de un ejercicio que me mandaron, dice de crear un programa que permita del usuario introducir su paralelo y su numero de curso hasta realizarlo de forma correcta, pero esa parte de realizarlo hasta que lo haga bien yo lo entiendo como si el usuario falla deba de hacerlo de  nuevo pero no se como podría hacerlo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int n = 0;
    char p = ' ';

    do{
        printf("Ingrese su paralelo: ");
        scanf("%c",&p);
        printf("Ingrese su numero de aula: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }while((p < 'A' || p > 'H') && (n > 1 && n <= 8));

    printf("lo ha realizado de forma correcta");

    return 0;
}
```

Todavía no lo termino pero esa parte de ahí no la entendí muy bien o no es con un do while sino solo while (o un if /else o un for ) la verdad no se.

Comment: la letra del paralelo debe ser desde la A a la H?

Comment: El programa es en [tag:c++] o es en [tag:c], decídete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correcto, lo has entendido bien, si el usuario ingresa datos que no son los esperados entonces el programa debe ser capaz de detectarlo y volver a solicitar el dato, y dejara de solicitarlos hasta que los datos sean los correctos, por lo tanto es logico pensar en un ciclo que "atrape" el caso incorrecto y que haga tantas iteraciones como intentos fallidos, por ejemplo un cajero automatico, para sacar dinero le tenemos que decir el monto, pero el monto minimo permitido es de 100 y el maximo permitido es de 500, entonces el caso incorrecto que el programa tiene que atrapar serian todos aquellos montos que estan por debajo del minimo y los que estan por encima del maximo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int minimo = 100;
    int maximo = 500;
    int montoRetiro;

    // solicitar monto
    printf("Ingrese monto a retirar: ");
    scanf("%d",&montoRetiro);

    // atrapar caso incorrecto
    while(montoRetiro < minimo || montoRetiro > maximo){
        // avisar fallo producido
        printf("- Error: el monto excede el rango permitodo\n\n");
        // volver a solicitar monto
        printf("Ingrese monto a retirar: ");
        scanf("%d",&montoRetiro);
    }

    printf("\n- Monto retirado con exito\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

en tu caso deberas hacer dos ciclos uno para paralelo y otro para el numero de curso